# Calculating Bill (Array and Do Loop for Java)

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop

I'm having trouble with my online lab, I'm given this code below and I can only modify the places where it says '// FIX ME'. I've already added the following answers in the blanks but I still don't have it quite right. I was thinking about writing another code on top asking for how many items I would like to input and then creating a DO Loop centered around that but this isn't what the question wants from me. It's possible that I'm just looking at this the wrong way, any help would be appreciated!

Here is the Lab;

The following program should input a list of items, including the description of the item, the number of items purchased and the unit price of the item; then calculate the total bill. The input of the list is complete when "Finish" is entered for the description. Complete the program so that it works correctly.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class CalculateBill {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        double sum = 0;
        double cost;
        int items;
        double unitPrice;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the item (Finish to end):");
        String description = scan.next();

        while( items != 0 ) { // FIX-ME
        System.out.println("Please enter the quantity of " + description + ": " );
        items = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter the unit price of " + description + ": ");
        unitPrice = scan.nextDouble();
        cost = Price++   ; // FIX-ME
        System.out.printf("Cost of %d %s(s) is $%.2f%n", items, description, cost);
        sum = sum+1; // FIX-ME
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the item (Finish to end):");
        description = scan.next();
        }

        System.out.printf("The total bill is $%.2f%n" ???  ); // FIX-ME
}
```

}

Comment: What don't you understand about the assignment? How would you compute this bill by hand? How does that differ from what the code is doing? (The point of this assignment is for *you* to analyze the code, not us.)

Comment: Answer this kind of question is just for SO. I'll pass it specially as @keshlam summarize it well.

Comment: I'm confused about the DO While loop, how do I make it stop after so many inputs. The input isn't set, it could be any number of variables. For @keshlam, like I have already said; I've analysed it and I'm stuck. As for @Orel-Eraki; I appreciate all of your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did to get it working:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CalculateBill {
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    double sum = 0;
    double cost = 0;
    int items=0;
    double unitPrice;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the name of the item (f to end):");
    // changed to f as I don't want to have to type Finish every time
    String description = scan.next();

    while( !description.equals("f") ) { // FIXED
    System.out.println("Please enter the quantity of " + description + ": " );
    items = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter the unit price of " + description + ": ");
    unitPrice = scan.nextDouble();
    cost = items*unitPrice  ; // FIXED
    System.out.printf("Cost of %d %s(s) is $%.2f%n", items, description, cost);
    sum += cost; // FIXED
    System.out.println("Please enter the name of the item (F to end):");
    description = scan.next();
    }

    System.out.printf("The total bill is $%.2f%n", sum); // FIXED
}

}
```

Comment: No problem.  I just edited the 3rd FIX-ME: it does the same thing, but using a short cut.